# Rubymotion ask for Xcode 4.x, but that version is already installed

Tags: xcode4, rake, rubymotion

I tried to ran rake in a rubymotion project and he shows the following error message

> ERROR! Xcode 4.x or greater is required

But I have Xcode 4.3.2 installed on my Mac

What can I do?

PD: I installed Xcode 4.4.1 and now the error is this

```
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36: command not found: /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -version
     Build ./build/iPhoneSimulator-5.1-Development
sh: /Applications/Xcode: No such file or directory
sh: /Applications/Xcode: No such file or directory
sh: /Applications/Xcode: No such file or directory
   Compile ./app/app_delegate.rb
sh: /Applications/Xcode: No such file or directory
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (127): [/Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Develop...]
Tasks: TOP => default => simulator => build:simulator
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: Is your RubyMotion up to date? (1.23), and do you have the Xcode Command Line Tools installed? (Settings > Downloads > Command Line Tools). `rake` works fine for me with Xcode 4.3.3

Comment: Yes, I have rubymotion 1.23 and I have the Command Line Tools. My version of Xcode is 4.3.2, but I don't know how ti upgrade ti 4.3.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you have an old version of Xcode also installed on your system. From the "Getting Started" page on RubyMotion's web site:

If you happened to have an older version of Xcode installed on your machine before you installed a newer Xcode from the App Store, you may want to type the following command in order to properly set up the default Xcode path.

```
$ sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```